What is the reflect-metadata equivalent of TC39: proposal-decorator-metadata
I'm looking for is something like below from this typescript documentation. I want to annotate some class fields with a particular metadata, and read all the fields through Reflect.ownKeys() but filter out the fields with a specific metadata.
class Greeter {
  @format("Hello, %s")
  greeting: string;
  constructor(message: string) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }
  greet() {
    let formatString = getFormat(this, "greeting");
    return formatString.replace("%s", this.greeting);
  }
}

import "reflect-metadata";
const formatMetadataKey = Symbol("format");
function format(formatString: string) {
  return Reflect.metadata(formatMetadataKey, formatString);
}
function getFormat(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
  return Reflect.getMetadata(formatMetadataKey, target, propertyKey);
}

It appears typescript 5.2 have merged the stage 3  proposal-decorator-metadata with this PR. However, I literally copied the example from Typescript 5.2 documentation for decorator metadata but it doesn't work in the latest (Typescript 5.5) version nor 5.2 version. I'm getting various compile errors and context.metadata is read-only and undefined
How can I have something similar to above code example using latest (Typescript 5.5) without reflect-metadata?
